# phantomjs not working with nodejs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I have tried everything that I was able to find on the internet, but I am not able to make phantomjs work on my ubuntu 14.04 server.

Here is my nodejs code snippet:

```
phantom.create("--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes",function(ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(page) {
    return page.open(htmlfilepath, function(status) {
        page.paperSize = { format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait', border: '1cm' };

        page.render(pdffilepath, function(){
          ph.exit();
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

The code is working fine on my local system (mac os x). I have installed phantomjs on my local system using brew.

On my server, I installed phantomjs using apt-get, and it is giving the following error on running the code:

```
phantom stderr: Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
```

And the following is the debug trace:

```
phantom stderr: Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag                                                                                                   [47/205]                                                                                                          
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=<filename>' to enable persisten cookie storage)       [45/205]                                                           
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration                                                                                                 [43/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      0 objectName : ""                                                                                                                           [42/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      1 cookiesFile : ""                                                                                                                          [41/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      2 diskCacheEnabled : "false"                                                                                                                [40/205]                                                                                                   
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1"                                                                                                   [38/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      4 ignoreSslErrors : "true"                                                                                                                  [37/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      5 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false"                                                                                                   [36/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      6 outputEncoding : "UTF-8"                                                                                                                  [35/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      7 proxyType : "http"                                                                                                                        [34/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      8 proxy : ":1080"                                                                                                                           [33/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      9 proxyAuth : ":"                                                                                                                           [32/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      10 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8"                                                                                                                 [31/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      11 webSecurityEnabled : "false"                                                                                                             [30/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      12 offlineStoragePath : ""                                                                                                                  [29/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      13 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"                                                                                                        [28/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      14 printDebugMessages : "true"                                                                                                              [27/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      15 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true"                                                                                                        [26/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      16 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true"                                                                                                       [25/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      17 sslProtocol : "sslv3"                                                                                                                    [24/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      18 sslCertificatesPath : ""                                                                                                                 [23/205]
                                                                                                                                                                         [22/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      19 webdriver : ":"                                                                                                          [21/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      20 webdriverLogFile : ""                                                                                                                    [20/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      21 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO"                                                                                                               [19/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      22 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : ""                                                                                                            [18/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments                                                                                                            [17/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      script: "/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/phantom/shim.js"                                                                                     [16/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      0 arg: "57128"                                                                                                                              [15/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG]      1 arg: "127.0.0.1"                                                                                                                          [14/205]
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode                                                                                                          [13/205]
                                                                                                                                                                         [12/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""                                                                                                          [11/205]
                                                                                                                                                                         [10/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )                                                    [9/205]
                                                                                                                                                                          [8/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )                                                [7/205]
                                                                                                                                                                          [6/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/_coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )                                        [5/205]
                                                                                                                                                                          [4/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/package.json" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )                            [3/205]
                                                                                                                                                                          [2/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )    [1/205]
                                                                                                                                                                          [0/205]
phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./lexer.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././rewriter.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./parser.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./nodes.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././scope.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./././helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././lexer.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./././rewriter.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )  

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame "<!--framePath //<!--frame0-->-->" 
2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 11 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 6 ( "SSL handshake failed" ) URL: "https://d1fxtkz8shb9d2.cloudfront.net/sockjs-0.3.min.js" 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame "<!--framePath //<!--frame1-->-->" 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 11 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 6 ( "SSL handshake failed" ) URL: "https://d1fxtkz8shb9d2.cloudfront.net/sockjs-0.3.min.js" 

phantom stderr: 2016-07-08T02:12:50 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 100
```

Any help on how this error can be fixed will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, this issue was resolved after installing the newer version of phantomjs. I have tried 1.9.7 and 1.9.8, both were this the above error on my system. After installing phantomjs-2.1.1, the issue was automatically resolved.

The steps below were used to install phantomjs-2.1.1:

```
cd /usr/local/share
sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo tar xjf phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```